# How i can use Mathematical induction to prove CFG production?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, context-free, proof-techniques, induction

If I have production $G_n$

> $S \rightarrow A_i b_i \quad$ for $1 \le i \le n$
>
> $A_i \rightarrow a_j A_i \mid a_j\quad$   for $1 \le i$ and $i \ne j$

1. Prove $G_n$ is sub-productions from $2n^2 - n$
2. Prove $G_n$ is $LR(0)$ production from $2^n + n^2 + n$

Comment: Welcome to MSe! It really help readability if you pose your questions using [*MathJax*](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I updated your question, but please verify I got it correct. Also, it helps the MSE Community know where you are having issues if you tell us what you have tried and where you are confused/stuck. Regards

Comment: I understand what the productions of $G_n$ are, but what do you mean by ‘sub-productions from $2n^2-n$’ and ‘$LR(0)$ production from $2^n+n^2+n$’? $G_n$ has $n$ productions of the first type and $n^2-n$ of the second type, so it has $2n^2-n$ productions altogether; if that’s what the first question asks you to prove, it does not require induction.

Comment: First Request: i used math induction to prove, but i don't know if this way is true.
Second: i don't know how prove

Comment: I don't quite understand the phrasing of the question. Assuming it concerns a proof that the given grammar(s) generate(s) some language(s), I'm closing as a duplicate of the (new) reference question.